# Setting headers using the /bin/mail command

Tags: email, mail-command

I have a bash script that I use with nagios that sends notifications by email. The key part of it looks like this:

```
# $1 (FROM) | $2 (TO) | $3 (SUBJECT) | $4 (BODY)
/usr/bin/printf "%b" "$4" | /bin/mail -s "$3" "$2" -- -f $1
```

I know I could use the `sendmail` command directly ([like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/172390/can-i-set-the-in-reply-to-header-when-using-the-linux-mail-command)) but it would mean reworking a few scripts to take care of building the entire message including all headers.

Is there any way to specify additional SMTP headers using `/bin/mail`, in my own case I am trying to add the `Importance: high` header?

I'm running exim 4.63 as my MTA and CentOS 5.6 x64.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many different versions of `mail` (see [Mail vs. mail what is the difference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26350/mail-vs-mail-what-is-the-difference/26361#26361) and the Heirloom project's [write-up on the different versions of `mail`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx_history.html)).

If you want to keep your sanity, I recommend avoiding any tool whose name is too close to `mail`. [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) is a lean text mode mail client which is often available, very flexible, and behaves the same everywhere.

```
mutt -H - "$2" <<EOF
From: $1
To: $2
Subject: $3
Importance: high

$4
EOF
```

Comment: What's does the middle standalone `-` do?

Comment: @Kev The option `-H` takes an argument, a file to read the mail contents (headers plus body) from. I pass the argument `-`, meaning to read standard input (and not a file called `-`; this is a very common convention in the unix world).

Comment: Thanks Gilles, works a treat. I never knew about the `-` convention before, will remember that in future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `-a` flag, e.g. `-a "Importance: high"`.

Comment: -1 As per the linked server fault post, that doesn't work.

Comment: For Heirloom mailx 12.4 this option is `-a filename` (Attach the given file to the message). Not what I was looking for!

Comment: The -a option (for adding custom headers) is for bsd-mailx, not by heirloom-mailx. I do not see an equivalent option to add headers for heirloom-mailx.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way.  Header syntax is complicated and tools like `mail` were designed to limit user exposure to it.  To use arbitrary headers you should submit the message using sendmail.

Comment: saying that there's no way to do something is almost always likely to be incorrect.  That said, the mailx command based on Berkeley mail and w/compat w/the POSIX mailx cmd, allows "-S" to set a var on cmdline; where you can set a replacement sendmail, where you code have any language implementing a filter to add custom headers that would then submit the result to sendmail.  Unix was designed to provide multiple ways to do things.  It would be very unlikely that one of those ways wouldn't do what you want.